# How to open the SQL database in crystal report?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, crystal-reports

How to open the sql data base in crystal report?

Using VB 6, SQL server 2000, Crystal Report 8.5

My code.

```
CR.DataFiles(0) = App.Path & "\Database\DUAL_ACS.mdf"
CR.ReportFileName = App.Path & "\rpt_attendancereport.rpt"
CR.Action = 1
```

But it showing “Cannot Open Sql Server”

What wrong in my code.

Need VB 6 code Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
CR.DataFiles(0) = App.Path & "\Database\DUAL_ACS.mdf"
```

try

```
CR.Connect = <<connection string to SQL Server goes here>>
```

Connection string should be in the format:

```
"DSN=<<server name here>>;" & _
"UID=<<user name here>>;" & _
"PWD=<<password here>>;" & _
"DSQ=<<database name here>>"
```

Just to clarify the 'DSN' bit isn't actually a DSN; rather, it has been overloaded to mean 'SQL Server name'.